# In wordpress' twentyfourteen theme, what template contains the class named site?

Tags: wordpress

Inside the style.css, we can see that .site {} is being styled. But i can not see any template within twentyfourteen' theme containing class="site".
I would kike to see what element this class is being applied to
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's located in your theme's `header.php`. [Line 34 for twenty-fourteen](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/header.php#L34). This file is then included by wordpress at the top of each page template.